# Python Round Robin

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to create a program that is able to take a list of names and create all the possible individual matchups that can take place.

The code isn't completely done yet.

I keep getting an error message when I try to call the function saying

> list index is out of range for line 7, aka "for s in lst[c+1:]".

Can someone help explain this to me and perhaps correct it?

Thanks.

```
import random
def pairShuffling(*names):
    lst = list(names)
    lst2=[]
    for c in range(len(names)):
        if lst[c]!=lst[-1]:
            for s in lst[c+1:]:
                lst2 += [lst[c],lst[s]]
    return lst2
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm

Comment: Note that the index starts from 0. If there are 4 names, then `lst` is of length 4. So `c` is 0, 1, 2, 3. Therefore `c+1` can become 4, and `lst[4]` is out of range.

Comment: @LoMaPh No, because they're checking before `if lst[c] != lst[-1]`, so if it ISN'T the last object, then it takes the next one.

(Which works obviously iff they're not duplicate but I suppose they're not)

Comment: @Fukiyel But `s` does go out of index (in `lst[s]`)

Answer (score 4):

The standard library [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html) module has a function called `combinations()`  that does what you are requesting (generating a list of all possible combinations of items from an iterable). If you are looking for permutations though, that is if `(A,B)` should be treated as distinct from `(B,A)`, then you would want to use `permutations()`.

For example, running the following code:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations

names = ['Jeff', 'Alice', 'Trogdor', 'Kublai Khan']

print("Combinations: ", [n for n in combinations(names, 2)])
print("Permutations: ", [n for n in permutations(names, 2)])
```

...will print the following output:

```
Combinations:  [('Jeff', 'Alice'), ('Jeff', 'Trogdor'), ('Jeff', 'Kublai Khan'), ('Alice', 'Trogdor'), ('Alice', 'Kublai Khan'), ('Trogdor', 'Kublai Khan')]
Permutations:  [('Jeff', 'Alice'), ('Jeff', 'Trogdor'), ('Jeff', 'Kublai Khan'), ('Alice', 'Jeff'), ('Alice', 'Trogdor'), ('Alice', 'Kublai Khan'), ('Trogdor', 'Jeff'), ('Trogdor', 'Alice'), ('Trogdor', 'Kublai Khan'), ('Kublai Khan', 'Jeff'), ('Kublai Khan', 'Alice'), ('Kublai Khan', 'Trogdor')]
```

On a side note, there happens to also be [an example](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for "round-robin" iteration (cycling through a set of iterables, pulling one at a time from each, until they are exhausted) using the itertools functions `islice()` and `cycle()`. But the term "round robin" doesn't accurately describe what you are trying to do. A better title for your question would be "generating combinations in python", or something to that effect.

Comment: I added a code example. Hope you don't mind; feel free to revert if you do.

Comment: Ben - Thanks! I was actually just in the process of adding one myself when you edited, though, so I went ahead and added it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your code:

```
import random
def pairShuffling(*names):
    lst = list(names) # maximum allowed index for lst[idx]` will be in range 0..len(names)-1
    lst2=[]
    for c in range(len(names)): # `c` will be in range[0..len(names)-1] 
        if lst[c]!=lst[-1]:
            for s in lst[c+1:]: # you overexceeding maximum allowed value for index
                lst2 += [lst[c],lst[s]]
    return lst2
```

I suppose you need to use [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) or `itertools.combinations`/`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`